# tiny-slider click listener registering too late

Tags: javascript, slider

I am looking for a vanilla js alternative to slick.js. I'm trying to replace it with [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider). I only have one issue though, as I am using Kentico & asp.net, everything is wrapped in a form tag.

With slick, if I check the event listeners for the dot buttons, it's registered before the form listener (and slick takes care of the rest with `event.preventdefault`).

With tiny-nav, no matter where I place my script tags and no matter where I load the lib from (head, body, inline), the tiny-slider is the last in line in the event listener queue. This means clicking on the dots (ie button) submits the page.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: Here's the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { //also same result with $(function(){
    tns({
        container: '.my-slider',
        autoplay: true,
        items: 1,
        autoplayButtonOutput: false,
        lazyload: true,
        controlsContainer: '.slider-controls',
        controlsPosition: 'bottom',
        navPosition: 'bottom'
        //navContainer: 'dots-container'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, the problem is that control buttons of Tiny-Slider trigger `<form>` instead of controlling slider? 
In this case, you've got to add `type="button"` to every `<button>` out there in this script, because by default (if not specified) every `<button>` comes with `type="submit"` and because of that, it triggers the `<form>`. When adding said parameters, make sure the `type="submit"` comes right after the `<button>` tag, example: `<button type="button" data-controls="prev" tabindex="-1">`. 

I just started using Tiny-Slider and stumbled upon this exact problem, so I thought I could share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solution to this problem Andrey.

The way I implemented the solution was to run the following after the slider was initiated...

```
    const tnsDotItems = document.querySelectorAll('.tns-nav button');
    if (tnsDotItems.length) {
        [].forEach.call(tnsDotItems, function (e) {
            e.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        });
    }
```

This fixed the dots, and maybe would also have to do the prev and next buttons with '.tns-controls button' if required.